# EF6 Retrying procedure throws "The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection" for SqlQuery command

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use the DBExecutionStrategy to retry queries that have timed out, but when the time out happens I get the error "The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection". I'm using EF6.

My Query:

```
using (var ctx = new EntityModel())
{
    IEnumerable<ItemResponse> items= ctx.Database.SqlQuery<ItemResponse>(
           "spItemListGet @UserID", new SqlParameter("@UserID", UserID)
    ).ToList();
}
```

My Execution Strategy:

```
protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception ex)
{
    bool retry = false;

    SqlException sqlException = ex as SqlException;
    if (sqlException != null)
    {
        int[] errorsToRetry =
        {
            -2,     //Timeout
        };
        if (sqlException.Errors.Cast<SqlError>().Any(x => errorsToRetry.Contains(x.Number)))
        {
            retry = true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw ex; //dont retry
        }
    }

    return retry;
}
```

The stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentException: The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Validate(Int32 index, Object value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.AddRange(Array values)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateStoreCommand(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass65`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__64()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass65`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__63()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String commandText, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass14`1.<ExecuteSqlQuery>b__13()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

What could it be done to prevent this error? Can Database.SqlQuery be used for with the execution strategy?

Comment: The execution strategy works fine when I try ctx.SaveChanges(). Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: No, you can't do this (if your command has parameters).

The long answer:
Here is a minimal repro of the issue. I stripped out the execution strategy from the picture, and faked it with a loop instead. This logic is implemented in the [ObjectContext](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/Objects/ObjectContext.cs), specifically in the `ExecuteStoreQueryInternalAsync` method. The problem seems to be that a `command.Parameters.Clear()` call is missing from the cleanup part.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestQuery();
}

private static void TestQuery()
{
    using (var ctx = new ProductContext())
    {
        var parameter = new SqlParameter("@ID", 1);
        var commandText = "select * from product where ProductId = @ID";

        Action a = () =>
        {
            IDbCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandText = commandText;
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            command.Connection = ctx.Database.Connection;
            if (command.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
            }

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                throw new Exception();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var pId = reader["ProductID"];
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //for simplification, we just swallow this error, but in reality the connection error
                //would reach the IDbExecutionStrategy, and would do a retry. Instead we fake the retry
                //with a loop below
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Dispose();

                //command.Parameters.Clear();  <--------- THIS LINE IS MISSING FROM EF
                command.Dispose();
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // we fake the retry with a loop now
        {
            a();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More information about EF6 bug here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/107283972666babbff10fb7409298f39200acb09

Comment: Huh, nice. Fixed 11 days ago.

Comment: @Tamas This does not seem to be fixed in EF 6.1.3  If a user has setup a retry in the DbExecutionStrategy and called dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand in their code, they will run into the Sql Parameter exception listed above.

Comment: EF 6.2+ has the fix. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/81

Comment: This issue is happening for me with EF 6.4.4 without using retries, see here: https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/81